# OpenCart 1.5 skips a part of url

Tags: php, opencart

My client has a website built using open cart 1.5. He wants me to create a folder inside of it and make a test website using the existing site. I copied everything from the live site and pasted it inside a folder in the live site. Every link in the test website is similar to the links in the live website.

href structure of the live: `href="www.site.com/resources"`

href stucture of the test site: `href="www.site.com/folder_name/resources"`

I noticed that when I clicked on a link in the test website, it redirects me to the live website even though I changed the link's href to something like this:  `href="www.site.com/folder_inside_the_live/resources"`.

Why does opencart ignore the `/folder_inside_the_live/`?

I noticed that the live site has no .htaccess  and I am afraid to create one as it might affect the live site entirely.

Comment: did you change the configuration of you test site ?

Answer (score 0):

If OpenCart has an installer, you may wish to check for any config/settings files, where it might have set-up the base for links. Reading [this](http://docs.opencart.com/installation) OpenCart docs page, it looks like these config files are at `/filePathToOpenCart/config.php` and `/filePathToOpenCart/admin/config.php`. Have a look at those, and see if they contain anything that could help. They are most likely just storing database names/passwords, but it is probably a good idea to check it anyway.